# Full-Text Search is not installed, or a full-text component cannot be loaded

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I am currently attempting to create a full text index on a unique column. The table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DictionaryWords](
       [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
       [Word] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
       [Frequency] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_DictionaryWords] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
       [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
CONSTRAINT [UX_Word] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
       [Word] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I then created the full text catalogue:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ft AS DEFAULT
```

and finally attempted to create the full text index:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON DictionaryWords(Word) KEY INDEX UX_Word
```

but I get the error:

```
Full-Text Search is not installed, or a full-text component cannot be loaded
```

Full text search is installed, as testified by the command:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')
```

which returns a value of 1. So presumably the problem is that "full-text component cannot be loaded".

Any ideas what I should look at next?

Comment: Did you copy/paste the error into Google and look at the different solutions? If so, tell us what you tried and if it worked or not so we don't duplicate your efforts.

Comment: All the Google articles i could find dealt with the fact that the Full Text component was not installed in the first place.

After much faffing I manage to get it to work (See answer below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the problem is that the full text catalogue was created BEFORE the full text component was installed.

I was fortunate to be have the luxury to drop the database and recreate the tables from scratch. The above three commands now worked.

If I couldn't drop the database, then probably deleting the full text catalogue and then recreating it would solve it (better than my drop database sledgehammer approach!)

Answer (score 51):

That's how I turned it on:

- Open: **SQL Server Installation Center**
- Click on **Installation** and then on **New SQL Server stand-alone installation...**
  [image]
- Navigate to the installation folder, look like this:
  [image]
  and select the folder that ends with **ENU**
- In the setup process just click next until you get to the **Installation Type** and then you check the **"Add features to an existing instance of SQL Server..."**
  [image]
- Click next to the **Feature Selection** and there you should pick **"Full-Text and Semantic for search"**
  [image]
- click next, next, next until the end

For those who **do not have** "SQL Server Installation Center", you can go to Control Panel > Programs > Unistall or ... and find for ex: **Microsft SQL Server 2017 (64-bit) , not Setup**, LocalDB, NativeClient or T-SQL, right-click > Unistall or change and **choose Add**.

Comment: Thank you, nice answer ! For those who doesn't have "SQL Server Installation Center", you can go to Control Panel > Programs > Unistall or ... and find for ex: Microsft SQL Server 2017 (64-bit) , not Setup, LocalDB, NativeClient or T-SQL,  right-click > Unistall or change and choose Add.

Comment: @AbdellahGRIB this is a very useful comment. I will update it in the answer .